# How can i drop a check constraint without deleting and recreating the table in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I have this table and i added a check to the column duree
with this condition `alter table operation modify Duree integer check(Duree>=2);`
but in the homework it's specified that it needs to be like (duree>=44) isntead
how this be fixed.

```
create table Operation (
CodeOP varchar(20) not null , 
Duree integer , 
Chef integer , 
DateDeb Date , 
Budget float , 
CodeS varchar (20),
constraint pk_operation primary key (CodeOP),

constraint fk_operation foreign key(CodeS)REFERENCES Service(CodeS) on delete set null
```

i tried  `alter table operation modify Duree integer check(Duree>=44);`

but i'm getting this message :

`ERROR at line 1: ORA-02293: cannot validate (TPBDD2.SYS_C008292) - check constraint violated`

Comment: "check constraint violated" - it means you have _at least_ one (and possibly many more) invalid value in your table. You need to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` it to correct it.

Comment: @Dai So i have to delete all the inserted tuples that don't satisfy the new condition, alter the table and then reinsert them back, i think that would work, thanks.

Comment: You should run `SELECT * FROM Operation WHERE Duree < 2` first, then once that looks okay do `DELETE FROM Operation WHERE Duree  < 2` - or you could `UPDATE` if you know what to replace the values with.